# DateTimeZone warning in symfony2 forms

Tags: forms, datetime, symfony

I'm getting strange error in my symfony2 based application. On every page which uses forms I get

```
E_WARNING: DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone (1024)
```

FYI, I'm invoking

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Warsaw");
```

in AppKernel::init(). Any idea how to get rid of this warning? Thanks in advance.

### Edit

This is my stack trace from NewRelic

```
…or/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Stub/StubIntlDateFormatter.php (542)
…or/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/DateType.php (274)
…or/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/DateType.php (88)
…/shared/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ResolvedFormType.php (167)
…/shared/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ResolvedFormType.php (164)   
…/shared/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ResolvedFormType.php (126)
…zy.pl/shared/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php (87)  
…zy.pl/shared/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php (114)
…zy.pl/shared/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php (342)
…zy.pl/shared/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php (230)
…zy.pl/shared/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/in Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder::getForm called at /var/www/tumamoczy.pl/shared/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php FormFactory.php (47)
…endor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Form/Factory/FormFactory.php (33)
…endsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Controller/RegistrationController.php (48)
in FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController::registerAction called at ? (?)
…alled at /var/www/tumamoczy.pl/releases/20130602213844/app/bootstrap.php.cache (1003) 
…alled at /var/www/tumamoczy.pl/releases/20130602213844/app/bootstrap.php.cache (977)
…alled at /var/www/tumamoczy.pl/releases/20130602213844/app/bootstrap.php.cache (1103)
…alled at /var/www/tumamoczy.pl/releases/20130602213844/app/bootstrap.php.cache (413)
…el::handle called at /var/www/tumamoczy.pl/releases/20130602213844/web/app.php (21)
```

It looks that warning appears in StubIntlDateFormatter.php, am I right? So is it a Symfony2 problem? Is it even solvable?

Comment: Does it give you a line number where this error is happening. I have tried putting your code in the same place and my date times adjust as expected

Comment: I added a stack trace from a NewRelic, maybe it can help in helping me ;)

Comment: does your php have the extension php_intl enabled?